# Mark Flash content as important for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash

Since the latest update, Chrome automatically pauses Flash content that it considers to be unimportant (see [Techcrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2015/06/04/chrome-now-automatically-pauses-flash-content-that-isnt-central-to-a-web-page/#.0ohxhl:GjBY)). However, for my site this means that the header is totally blocked, which really fraks up the design. I know it's better to use HTML5 and I'm working on a new version, but in the meanwhile, is it possible to mark the header as important?

Answer (score 0):

The viewable area of the Flash object needs to be at least 400px x 300px for Chrome to consider it 'important.'

Comment: Also, if the swf is on the same domain as the page URL it will not get paused.  (If the swf is in an iFrame, the swf's domain need to match the top-level page domain, not the iFrame's domain.)